# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Intento crear una función que me transforme una columna de elementos de tipo string a float, estoy intentando crear una función que le pueda pasar la clave de la columna que quiero cambiar para no tener que hacer una función para cada columna, aquí dejo un ejemplo de un dataframe que creo yo con las excepciones que quiero que controle la función

```
def float_money(row, row_):
    row = row[row_]
    if not "," in row:
        lon = len(str(row))
        row = np.round(float(row) / (10**lon), 2)
    else:
        row = float(row.replace(",", "."))
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame({"hola" : ["Hola", "Ciao"], "el_flotante" : ["17,39", "250"]}, index=[1, 2])

df = df.apply(float_money(row = df, row_="el_flotante"), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Al final me deja el siguiente error

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Hay varias cosas. Tienes métodos en pandas que hacen exactamente lo que quieres de manera mucho más sencilla. ¿Quieres hacerlo así específicamente por algo? El error te está dando por tratar de convertir una serie con `float()` cuando deberías usar `.astype(float)`, pero tu código de igual manera no va a devolver un dataframe si no una serie. Por otro lado para pasar argumentos en apply no se hace como lo has planteado

Comment: Ups, cierto, tienes razón. Borraré mi comentario.

Comment: borrado el mío también para no generar confusión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a especular bastante partiendo de lo que estás intentando hacer en la condición dentro de tu función `float_money` por lo que puede que esta respuesta no sea la que esperas.

---

Hay cosas que estás planteando mal.

Si utilizas `pd.apply()` pasarle el propio dataframe es redundante, ya que el propio `apply` itera por cada fila del dataframe.

Por otro lado estás intentando devolver una serie en lugar de un dataframe por lo que la asignación de variable que estás haciendo a la hora de hacer el apply en principio no es correcta.

Creo que lo que pretendes es convertir los números con decimales en formato #,## a `float`.

Y aquí viene mi *invent*: pretendes convertir los enteros que estén sin decimales a `float` pasando de ### a #.##, pero la forma que tienes de convertirlo no es correcta en absoluto. Ahora mismo en `lon` tienes la longitud de la representación en string de la serie `df[column_name]`, en tu caso 54.

Ahora quieres convertir 250 a float y dividirlo entre 10^54 para luego redondearlo a dos decimales que viene a ser... 0...

Cuando creo que lo único que quieres es dividir entre 100.

Así que modifico mi respuesta original, tiro tiple y a ver si te sirve.

---

Te propongo una alternativa un poco más simple

```
def float_money(row, column_name):
    if '.' in row[column_name]:
        return float(row[column_name])
    elif ',' in row[column_name]:
        return float(row[column_name].replace(',', '.'))
    else:
        return int(row[column_name]) / 100


df['el_flotante'] = df.apply(float_money, args=('el_flotante',), axis=1)
```

La función float_money recibe como parámetros la fila actual (`row`) y el nombre de la columna a convertir `column_name`.

- Si se encuentra un `.` en la posición a convertir damos por hecho que ya está en formato numérico y lo convierte a `float`.
- Si encuentra una `,` la sustituye por un `.` y lo convierte a `float``
- Si no hay ni comas ni puntos, convertimos a `int` y dividimos entre 100

**Resultado**

| hola | el_flotante |
| --- | --- |
| Hola | 17.39 |
| Ciao | 2.5 |

Comment: Yo también pensé en eso, pero luego pensé "si esa fuera la solución, ya la podría responder". Pero me temo que no hace lo mismo que la función del OP. Si miras su función, hace cosas diferentes dependiendo si la coma está o no. Eso implica que el OP si o si tendrá que hacer una modificación extra a la función propuesta.

Comment: Ay dios, creo que intuyo lo que está buscando el OP y espero estar equivocado... voy a modificar la respuesta

Comment: Me quedé con la intriga! Que intuyes???

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ha funcionado exactamente como necesitaba

Comment: De nada! Te entendí de rebote ^^' En próximas ocasiones intenta por favor aportar la mayor información posible :D

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución consiste en recorrer con un for cada nombre de la columna. A partir del nombre obtenemos la columna y le aplicamos a cada "celda" la función float_money. Espero que te sirva c:

###### Código

```
import pandas as pd

def float_money(value):
    if "," in value:
        return float(value.replace(",", "."))
    else:
        return round(float(value) / (10**len(value)), 2)

df = pd.DataFrame({"hola" : ["Hola", "Ciao"], "el_flotante" : ["17,39", "250"]}, index=[1, 2])

# el for se encargará de recorrer cada item de la tupla, que debería de ser el nombre
# de una columna. Puedes agregar las columnas que quieras aquí.
for columna in ("el_flotante",):
    # aplicamos la función float_money a cada valor de la columna "el_flotante" y reemplazamos la columna anterior por la nueva.
    # a la funcion float_money se le pasa un argumento que es el valor de una "celda" del DataFrame.
    df[columna] = df[columna].apply(float_money)

print(df)
```

###### Produce

```
   hola  el_flotante
1  Hola        17.39
2  Ciao         0.25
```